# how to compare 2 neo4j graphs

Tags: json, neo4j

Could you please help me to find the way to compare 2 Neo4j graphs. the result should be modeled by another color. For example if the difference between them is one node, this node should be in red color.

Regards.

Comment: What technology do you use and how do you want visualize those differences?

Comment: I use Neo4j as Database and PHP to develop my application. And to visualize the graph I use Alchemy. on the same graph I want to visualize the nodes added in different color

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use an d3 model where you set the source graphs of a node / relationship when you load the data, making sure that you merge the same nodes and rels to be just one.

Then when visualizing you could render them in 3 colors. e.g. green, red, blue depending if they belong to graph1, graph2 or both.